# Make main graph area depending on size of legends block

Tags: legend, echarts

Some of legend item with quite a big text content in it leads to situation when legend block is overlaping graph. As I know echarts has options to make legend block scrollable, but for my project this is not going to work out.
So maybe there is any ways to redraw main graph (to smaller one) if legend block is too big? and make this behavior sensitive for resize event.
Thank you for any advice.

here is the example of overlapping:
[image: here is the example of overlapping]
and this is my echarts config

```js
let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('myChart'));

let myChartOption = {
  "tooltip": {
    "show": true
  },
  "grid": {
    "containLabel": true,
    "borderColor": "transparent",
    "backgroundColor": "transparent",
    "show": true,
    "left": "3%",
    "right": "4%",
    "borderWidth": 0
  },
  "legend": {
    "orient": "horizontal",
    "x": "center",
    "y": "bottom",
    "formatter": "{name}",
    "borderColor": "rgba(178,34,34,0.8)",
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "padding": 15,
    "textStyle": {
      "color": "#000000"
    },
    "data": [{
      "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
      "icon": "circle"
    }, {
      "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
      "icon": "circle"
    }, {
      "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
      "icon": "circle"
    }, {
      "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
      "icon": "circle"
    }]
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "category",
    "boundaryGap": ["5%", "5%"],
    "data": ["январь 2015", "февраль 2015", "март 2015", "апрель 2015", "май 2015", "июнь 2015", "июль 2015", "август 2015", "сентябрь 2015", "октябрь 2015", "ноябрь 2015", "декабрь 2015", "январь 2016", "февраль 2016", "март 2016", "апрель 2016", "май 2016", "июнь 2016"],
    "axisLabel": {
      "fontSize": 9
    },
    "axisTick": {
      "alignWithLabel": true,
      "interval": 0
    }
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "axisLine": {
      "show": true
    },
    "axisTick": {
      "show": true
    },
    "type": "value",
    "splitLine": {
      "show": false
    },
    "position": "left"
  }],
  "series": [{
    "type": "line",
    "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
    "data": [5500, 11025, 6514, -3206, -975, -399, -3397, 5223, 1673, 13116, 13035, 29750, 26314, 33308, 36938, 38997, 32916, 31780],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#f33"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
    "data": [3000, 10820, 6925, 5785, 12675, 12450, 6700, 12660, 5390, 17125, 17980, 29955, 31015, 31110, 29405, 35235, 32025, 32535],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#fee"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
    "data": [1500, 1972, 2840, 856, 840, 68, 568, 3498, 3532, 3686, 5658, 5752, 1758, 5206, 7252, 6152, 9246, 8230],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#94c9fe"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
    "data": [1000, -320, 190, -1076, 0, 1876, 2385, 2336, 3084, 2450, -419, 1163, 342, 1201, 2404, 3240, 2766, 2036],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#fcabdb"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }]

};

myChart.setOption(myChartOption);
```

```css
#myChart {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.6.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: can you put your code here ? so we can check your current settings and provide possible solution

Answer (score 0):

There are two settings you have to add

`grid.bottom:'15%'`  , you set bottom grid reach before 15% of the height of your container

`legend.height:'15%'`, you set legend takes 15% of the height of your container

```
---------------
|   85% chart  |
|------------- |
|   15% legend |
----------------
```

**Result:** 
[image]

```js
let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('myChart'));

let myChartOption = {
  "tooltip": {
    "show": true
  },
  "grid": {
    bottom: '15%',
    "containLabel": true,
    "borderColor": "transparent",
    "backgroundColor": "transparent",
    "show": true,
    "left": "3%",
    "right": "4%",
    "borderWidth": 0
  },
  "legend": {
    height:'15%',
    "orient": "horizontal",
    "x": "center",
    "y": "bottom",
    "formatter": "{name}",
    "borderColor": "rgba(178,34,34,0.8)",
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "padding": 15,
    "textStyle": {
      "color": "#000000"
    },
    "data": [{
      "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
      "icon": "circle"
    }, {
      "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
      "icon": "circle"
    }, {
      "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
      "icon": "circle"
    }, {
      "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
      "icon": "circle"
    }]
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "category",
    "boundaryGap": ["5%", "5%"],
    "data": ["январь 2015", "февраль 2015", "март 2015", "апрель 2015", "май 2015", "июнь 2015", "июль 2015", "август 2015", "сентябрь 2015", "октябрь 2015", "ноябрь 2015", "декабрь 2015", "январь 2016", "февраль 2016", "март 2016", "апрель 2016", "май 2016", "июнь 2016"],
    "axisLabel": {
      "fontSize": 9
    },
    "axisTick": {
      "alignWithLabel": true,
      "interval": 0
    }
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "axisLine": {
      "show": true
    },
    "axisTick": {
      "show": true
    },
    "type": "value",
    "splitLine": {
      "show": false
    },
    "position": "left"
  }],
  "series": [{
    "type": "line",
    "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
    "data": [5500, 11025, 6514, -3206, -975, -399, -3397, 5223, 1673, 13116, 13035, 29750, 26314, 33308, 36938, 38997, 32916, 31780],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#f33"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
    "data": [3000, 10820, 6925, 5785, 12675, 12450, 6700, 12660, 5390, 17125, 17980, 29955, 31015, 31110, 29405, 35235, 32025, 32535],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#fee"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично",
    "data": [1500, 1972, 2840, 856, 840, 68, 568, 3498, 3532, 3686, 5658, 5752, 1758, 5206, 7252, 6152, 9246, 8230],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#94c9fe"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Тоже ООООчень большое и длинное название графика, что просто неприлично 2",
    "data": [1000, -320, 190, -1076, 0, 1876, 2385, 2336, 3084, 2450, -419, 1163, 342, 1201, 2404, 3240, 2766, 2036],
    "yAxisIndex": 0,
    "itemStyle": {
      "normal": {
        "color": "#fcabdb"
      }
    },
    "areaStyle": {}
  }]

};

myChart.setOption(myChartOption);
```

```css
#myChart {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.6.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution for this particular situation, but:  

1. After installing this option, the legend bug remained (it actually gone with 30% for me)  
2. This is not responsive solution - on a big screens i got huge gap between legend and main graph

Comment: I think it will be enough if I just figure out how to dynamically change "bottom" option for grid or "height" for legend on "resize" and "init" events.  
Or I should somehow render legend in another container...

Comment: you need to resize and change the corresponding option based on your div. here are the steps : 1) replace the % to a function with returns the % based on the parent div of your chart. 2) set the option again when the window is resized.

Comment: Well, looks like it works like this:    
  we loop around the legends array (it turned out so that I used the series array). And for the text of the legends element, we render as follows
1. Create a span with id = ruler  
2. apply styles to visually hide it  
3. while looping through the legends.data loop, insert the element text into this span and calculate its size (if the font and line-height are not specified, then take their default values). We get the total height of the elements and set it to grid.bottom  
4. On resize we just redraw graph via api

Comment: Is there a better solution in 2023? Will otherwise implement my own responsive function.